# ASP.NET MVC viewport not reformatting page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewport

This used to work: I created a brand new ASP.NET MVC 4 application using Visual Studo Pro SP1. I haven’t changed a thing. I’m using IE10. The default links at the top “Home About Contact” are right justified.  When I resize the browser narrower, they stay right justified. They used to become centered, as well as the footer text.

Like I said, this used to work. This is a brand new application with no changes. Does anyone know why this stopped working?

Comment: If the issue isn’t IE10 in the first place, perhaps you *should* provide some code or screenshot(s) for illustration.

Comment: Like I said, it's a brand new project, so if you create a new C# MVC4 application, you'll get the same thing I get.